# NetworkManager and keyfile to connect to WPA2 Entreprise

Tags: linux, networking, connection, networkmanager, wpa2

How can I use NetworkManager with keyfile to configure a Wi-Fi connection in WPA2-Entreprise?

Answer (score 0):

What kind of "keyfile"? WPA2-Enterprise has a boatload of possible authentication schemes, see http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Extensible_Authentication_Protocol. If you don't know then I would presume you have EAP-TLS. In that case, you'd pick

- Security: WPA & WPA2 Enterprise
- Authentication: TLS
- Identity: Your login name
- Private key: your key file